# Merge POST parameters in single property in my view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, html-helper

In my registration FORM, I have to allow the user to put his date of birth. It is a requirement, that I show a SELECT for the day, a SELECT for the month and a SELECT for the year.

I have worked out a Html helper extension that creates that schema, and names the controls `propertyName+".day"`, `propertyName+".month"` and `propertyName+".year"`.

The idea is that in my view model, I define a `DateTime` property and then invoke this helper: `@Html.DateSelect(m=>m.DateOfBirth)` , but the problem is that I don't know how to merge the previous 3 properties in a `DateTime` again.

I would get 3 POST parameters named `dateofbirth.day`, `dateofbirth.month` and `dateofbirth.year`.

How would it be done in MVC3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a custom model binder:

```
public class SplitDateTimeBinder : IModelBinder 
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

        ValueProviderResult day = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("propertyName.day");
        ValueProviderResult month = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("propertyName.month");
        ValueProviderResult year = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("propertyName.year");

        DateTime result = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), int.Parse(month), int.Parse(day));

        return user;
    }
}
```

and register it in Global.asax:

`ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new SplitDateTimeBinder());`

I've used `int.Parse()` in the example but you'll probably want to use `int.TryParse()` and handle failed parses properly.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a [custom model binder](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx).